# ON statement in SQL when followed by a BETWEEN statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

Based on the example from this book on site 299:
https://download.bibis.ir/Books/Database/SQL/2020/Learning_SQL_Generate,_Manipulate,_and_Retrieve_Data-bibis.ir.pdf

I wonder if there is a mistake in this SQL code at the ON statement?
Because I thought an ON statement is always a connection between 2 tables and in this example I do not really see the connection.

```
mysql> SELECT pymnt_grps.name, count(*) num_customers
-> FROM
-> (SELECT customer_id,
-> count(*) num_rentals, sum(amount) tot_payments
-> FROM payment
-> GROUP BY customer_id
-> ) pymnt
-> INNER JOIN
-> (SELECT 'Small Fry' name, 0 low_limit, 74.99
high_limit
-> UNION ALL
-> SELECT 'Average Joes' name, 75 low_limit, 149.99
high_limit
-> UNION ALL
-> SELECT 'Heavy Hitters' name, 150 low_limit,
9999999.99 high_limit
-> ) pymnt_grps
-> ON pymnt.tot_payments
-> BETWEEN pymnt_grps.low_limit AND
pymnt_grps.high_limit
-> GROUP BY pymnt_grps.name;
```

Comment: `do not really see the connection` - `ON pymnt.tot_payments BETWEEN pymnt_grps.low_limit AND pymnt_grps.high_limit`?

Comment: The on clause does not always have to be an equation operator.

Comment: There is no semantic difference between ON clauses and WHERE clauses,in fact in the really old days of SQL you put everything in the WHERE clause - there was no ON clause.  The ON clause was created for clarity, letting you segregate the part of the filter that pertains solely to the relationship between the two tables, but it does not matter, you can put the whole thing into the WHERE clause and still get the same result.  In this case Pymnt_grps is a range table and you want only that one applicable record that falls within (between) the range.

Comment: yeah, my mistake was, based on the tutorials I have seen, I thought ON always needs an equation (=) operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement (a subset of the overall query) forms 3 rows, with each row representing a non-overlapping "range" with a name:

```
SELECT 'Small Fry' name, 0 low_limit, 74.99 high_limit
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Average Joes' name, 75 low_limit, 149.99 high_limit
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Heavy Hitters' name, 150 low_limit, 9999999.99 high_limit
```

The overall query compares the value of `pymnt.tot_payments` to the `low_limit` and `high_limit` of the ranges. By making that comparison only 1 row from the 3 possible ranges will apply to each row of the payments table.

So, "the connection" for the 2 tables is where `pymnt.tot_payments` fits within the low & high limits. i.e. by using BETWEEN

```
SELECT
      pymnt_grps.name
    , count(*) num_customers
FROM (
    SELECT
          customer_id
        , count(*) num_rentals
        , sum(amount) tot_payments
    FROM payment
    GROUP BY customer_id
    ) pymnt
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT 'Small Fry' name, 0 low_limit, 74.99 high_limit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Average Joes' name, 75 low_limit, 149.99 high_limit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Heavy Hitters' name, 150 low_limit, 9999999.99 high_limit

    ) pymnt_grps 
          ON pymnt.tot_payments BETWEEN pymnt_grps.low_limit AND pymnt_grps.high_limit
GROUP BY
 pymnt_grps.name;
```

and by making that connection the overall query can count the number of payments that fall within each range.

As observed in comments, join conditions are not restricted to equality, using between as a join condition is perfectly valid and indeed quite common.

**nb** It is assumed that `pymnt.tot_payments` is positive and 2 decimal precision only and never larger than 9999999.99. With those assumptions the ranges will always match to a single row in the payments table.

Comment: Thanks so much. My problem was, that on all the tutorials I have seen, there is no hint that a ON can be followed by something other than an equation operator.

Comment: Any valid predicates, of the sort you might use in a where clause, can be used in joins. I have even seen case expressions used but I'm not a fan of that. Cheers.